# How to efficiently hotkey your units in production?

Tags: starcraft-2

Sometimes I am fighting and producing at the same time, but I find inefficient the way I add my production units to my army hotkeys.

I usually use my select all army key, to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+click the unit I produced, selecting all of the same type, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+group-number to reassemble it.

Is there any established way to do it more efficiently? I have pretty low skill but I am aiming to learn "the right way" from the start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you'd like to do is add units to an existing group. If you have your army on control group <kbd>5</kbd> for example, you can select the new units and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to add them to that control group instead of reassigning the control group to just those units.

You can select the new units however you like to do this, but generally you will have to look at them unless you already have them assigned to a key (I'm not counting <kbd>F2</kbd> for the moment). Depending on what race you play and how you like to do your production, you may find it useful to have a camera location saved where you have your production rallied so you can quickly switch there, add your units to control groups or give commands, then switch your attention elsewhere.

I'm not saying you shouldn't use <kbd>F2</kbd> at all, but it is generally considered a crutch and can cause you to move units in a sloppy way. It is usually better to add units to specific groups and use either those groups or your mouse for better control. For example, attack-moving your entire army more than a short distance will usually cause groups of units to separate significantly which your opponent may take advantage of. I don't believe there's any set of methods you absolutely must use to play the game well, but if you're looking for the "established way" then I would avoid controlling your whole army with one button.

Comment: Nice answer! I agree with what you said about F2, I use it just to select all units of the same type, not to moving. But I'm looking for a method to add new units to the group without looking at them,  in the lack of such answer I will accept yours.

Comment: @MoonKnight98 fair enough, you can select all with F2 then narrow your selection with a Ctrl click on the unit type you want.

Comment: @MoonKnight98 The proper way to "add units to group without looking at them" is definitely [Shift]+[group number]. Selecting **new** units without looking at them, though, is a problem without answer - there's no way to "select all units built from a building" or "select ungrouped units" or something similar. You have to select them manually, and then add to group.

Comment: @OrcJMR I suspected that, but since Starcraft players develop several methods for doing thing efficiently, I'm asking if there is an established method for that

Comment: @OrcJMR except for zerg, that you can assign to a group while having the larvae selected (while morphing)

Answer (score 1):

Another common technique is to use a camera hotkey to your army rally point, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click on unit types and assign/append them to your preferred hotkey group.

I guess it is easier as the zerg as you can assign/append the units to a control group when they're still cocoons, like you morph 8 Hydras that you assign to <kbd>1</kbd>, deselect and reselect your larvas and morph 8 Roaches that you assign to <kbd>2</kbd>, deselect and reselect again your larvas and morph 8 more Hydras who are going to be morphed into Lurkers later and assign them to <kbd>3</kbd>, that kind of stuff.

But again, even as zerg, you can still use a camera hotkey on an army rally point.